# How to count Boolean changes in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

My table looks like this

[image]

The goal is to count how many times the actuator_state of an specific actuator (from the column actuator_names) changes in a period of time. Keep in mind that a specific actuator has various actuators (For instance Heater has Heator0, Heator1, etc) and the goal is to count how many times has changed Heater0+ Heater1+ Heator2+ Heater3.... (Also the name of the table is state_actuator

I tried this:

```
SELECT actuator_nome AS NOME, 
SUM (DISTINCT CASE WHEN  actuator_state.actuator AND DISTINCT actuator_state.actuator_time AND DISTINCT actuator_state.actuator_state THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS TROCAS_ESTADO
FROM actuator_state WHERE actuator_time BETWEEN '2020-05-17 16:58:54' AND '2020-05-17 17:09:58' AND actuator_name='Heater'
```

The result should be
Heater: 5; 
(for instance Heater0 has changed 3 times and Heater1 two times and other Heaters 0 changes)

Comment: Please go easy on the ALL CAPS, especially in titles. It's considered YELLING. Secondly, tag only with the database you're actually using. You had this with MySQL and SQLite as well for no apparent reason.

Comment: Please provide data as *text*, never as image. Declare your version of Postgres and the actual (minimal) table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement)

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select 
    actuator_name,
    count(*) filter(where actuator_state <> lag_actuator_state) no_changes
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(actuator_state) 
            over(partition by actuator_name, actuator order by actuator_time) lag_actuator_state
    from mytable t
    where actuator_time between '2020-05-17 16:58:54' and '2020-05-17 17:09:58'
) t
group by actuator_name
```

The subquery uses `lag()` to retrieve the "previous" state of each actuator. Then, the outer query aggregates by `actuator_name`, and performs a count that increments by `1` everytime the consecutive values are not equal.

You can add additional filters in the `where` clause of the subquery as needed.

Note that this query does not count the first value in the period as a change. Only further changes are taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select actuator_name,
       count(*) filter (where prev_as is distinct from actuator_state)
from (select sa.*,
             lag(actuator_state) over (partition by actuator order by actuator_time) as prev_as
      from state_actuator sa
     ) sa
where actuator_time between '2020-05-17 16:58:54' and '2020-05-17 17:09:58'    
group by actuator_name;
```

You can filter on a particular name in the `where` clause as well.

Note that this counts the first appearance as a "change".  It is not clear if that matches your intention.